# Flux in two dimensions using pyhton sympy.vector.vector_integrate

Tags: python, math, sympy, flux

I am having trouble calculating the following example
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/line-integrals-in-vector-fields-articles/a/flux-in-two-dimensions

where F is [F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbCu3.png) and the parameterization r(t) is
[parameterization r(t)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbQvj.png)

```
from sympy import sin, cos, exp, pi, symbols
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, ParametricRegion, ImplicitRegion, vector_integrate
from sympy.abc import r, x, y, z, theta, phi,a
C = CoordSys3D('C')
F=C.x**2*C.i+C.y*C.j
display('F=',F)
semicircle = ParametricRegion((3*cos(theta), 3*sin(theta)), (theta, 0, 2*pi))
flux = vector_integrate(F, semicircle)
display('flux=',flux)
```

reference:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/vector_integration.html

Comment: I've looked at SymPy's source code: basically it doesn't consider the normal vector to the circle. I would consider opening an issue on [github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/) asking the developers for clarifications.

Comment: I just closed the issue. Please reopen if it is valid.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/24123